# JHipster: configuring log levels through jdl file

Tags: logging, jhipster, jdl

I am looking for a way to configure the microservices generated by jhipster using jdl file to precide which level of loggins i want to have.

Is there a way to do this using jdl file?

Hope to shed some lights about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make sense to generate logging configuration from JDL because it's so easy to modify logging levels either in `logback-spring.xml` or in `application.yml`.

Implementing this in JDL will never happen because it would be a violation of JHipster's [policy 2: "Only add options/features when there is sufficient added-value in the generated code"](https://www.jhipster.tech/policies/#policy-2-only-add-optionsfeatures-when-there-is-sufficient-added-value-in-the-generated-code)

Comment: yeah definitely, thanks a lot @Marziou